# What layout do spinners implement by default?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a layout with multiple spinners. Some have adapters while others get their contents from string arrays. The ones with the adapters implement the simple_list_item_1 layout, but this causes a different look than the other spinners and leads to formatting issues on the page. How does one find out, or does anyone know what layout a spinner uses by default?

Comment: Try checking out the `android:spinnerMode` [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html).

Comment: @TronicZomB    after a some fooling around with it I've been unable to find a satisfactory solution. all that spinnerMode does is give you the option of dialog or dropdown. my problem is that there is too much white space in the prepopulated selection in simple_list_item_1

Comment: OK it was worth a shot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A spinner's layout is dependent on the layout passed to it's adapter.

It looks like simple_list_item_1 is a simple TextView with padding:

Here's the source xml layout: https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/layout/simple_list_item_1.xml

Comment: agreed, but it is possible to have a spinner without an adapter. I'm feeding some lists with the android:entries item. whatever layout it is choosing to inflate the menu with upon selecting the spinner has more whitespace than simple_list_item_1 and I was looking for a way to find out what layout it was using so that I could make my adapter use that layout.

Comment: run uiautomatorviewer after the screen is loaded onto a device or emulator. Then click the litte phone icon in the top left corner, and it will dump all view hierarchies. At this point you can hover your mouse around and see exactly what elements it is made of.

Comment: I ended up fixing my problem by creating a custom layout without the padding.